# Как реализовать анимацию CSS

Tags: jquery, css, css3, sass, css-animation

При клике на кнопку 'добавить в корзину',как я понял копия картинки улетает в корзину и исчезает. 
Вот пример.
https://aupontrouge.ru/ru/alexander-wang-1425498-boots-botinki-chernyj

Comment: анимация от бога мне оч понравилось :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю как работают подобные скрипты, т.к. никогда не интересовали, но думаю как-то так)

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){ //При нажатии на кнопку..
  var buttonPos = $(this).offset(); //Определяем позицию кнопки..
  var basketPos = $('.basket').offset(); //Определяем позицию корзины
  var cardImg = $('.card .image img').attr('src');
  
  $('.card').append('<div class="addbasket-effect" style="position:absolute;z-index:999;">'+
                    '<img src="'+cardImg+'" width="100px">'+
                    '</div>'); // Создаём блок с эффектом
                    
  $('.addbasket-effect').css({ // Устанавливаем ему позицию кнопки
    'top': buttonPos.top,
    'left': buttonPos.left
  }).animate({ // А потом анимацию, с позицией корзины
    'top': basketPos.top,
    'left': basketPos.left
  },1000,'linear',function(){
    $('.addbasket-effect').remove(); // После окончания анимации - удаляем блок
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #888;
  text-align: right;
}
.top .basket {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top">
  <div class="basket">Корзина</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150">
  </div>
  <button>Добавить в корзину</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо друг! отлично)

Comment: @FedorVunecky, всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: а случайно нет информации как ее в полете уменьшить? пробовал свойство scale(0.5) - но джиквери его не знает кажется. Ширина не подходит фиксированная - просто ее обрезает на ходу и получается не красиво(

Comment: @FedorVunecky, почему-то `transform: scale(.5);` не захотел работать. Но получилось использовать `width: 10px; height: 10px;` - https://jsfiddle.net/wms8zta7/4/

Answer (score 3):

Вы правильно поняли, делается клон и анимируется.

```js
var $cart = $('#cart');
$('#tocart').on('click', function(){
  var $product = $('#product');
  $product
    .clone()
    .addClass('clone')
    .appendTo('body')
    .css({
      top: $product.offset().top,
      left: $product.offset().left
    })
    .animate({
      top: $cart.offset().top,
      left: $cart.offset().left,
      opacity: 0
    }, 1000, function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

```css
#cart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}

#product img {
  width: 200px;
}

#product.clone {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart"></div>
<button id="tocart">В корзину</button>
<div id="product"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a"></div>
```

Можно еще подогнать центр учитывая размеры корзины и картинки

Comment: Спасибо , выручили)